# Why custom 404 page duplicate in gatsby app

Tags: gatsby

I develop my first gatsby site with hello-world starter. It contains only index page + custom 404 page.

Through build there is info about generation of 3 static pages:

- index.hmtl;
- /public/404/index.html & /public/404.html, which are custom 404 page by content.

Wonder about reason to have similar file twice on different paths.

Is it related with routing mechanism or SEO/crawling purpose?

[Duplicate 404 page in gatsby app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4mQx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your screenshot that you have a custom 404.js and that's probably what you're expecting to see. By default, Gatsby provides a 404 page to help with development so if you go to a route that doesn't exist, you can see an index of all pages that have been generated. This is created by Gatsby.

On production, your custom 404 will be used, however it also has the route to 404.html because many static site hosting companies will direct 404 errors to this page.

From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-404-page/):

> Gatsby ensures that your 404 page is built as 404.html as many static hosting platforms default to using this as your 404 error page. If you’re hosting your site another way, you’ll need to set up a custom rule to serve this file for 404 errors.

Comment: So Gatsby do it only for me to check? Looks like redundant to have multiple similar files on production.